# Sum the column on certain condition in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

We have below format of  data in a txt file.Need to add the count(pid) on the basis of pid. Can we put awk logic .

```
pid Name count(pid)
4   a       24
5   b       22
4   a       21
3   c       20
5   b       4
3   c       43
```

Below is the expected result 
    Expected result!

```
pid Name count(pid)
4   a       45
5   b       26
3   c       63
```

Comment: Tried this command but it just sums up the columns directly not on conditional basis                                                                                       cat count.txt | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}

Comment: The answer linked by @Kent won't work for multiple columns as keys. Use this instead: `awk 'NR==1{h=$0;next}{a[$1,$2]+=$3}END{print h;for (i in a) {split(i,b,SUBSEP);print b[1],b[2],a[i]}}' file`

Comment: Not working for this case!!!